# Displaying Base64 String in ASP.Net Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview, base64

I have the task of displaying information using asp.net which requires string fields, which I easily implemented, and an image to go along with the information. I tried using an image field within my gridview to display a picture which worked well for images where I have a url to go along with them. However I have been trying to figure out a way to display an image that is stored as a base64 string. I've tried all sorts of ways to try and display the image, such as using a template field, trying to set the image URL to the string which would display a base64 in html, and even converting the base64 to an image which did not seem to work. Right now I am trying to just add data manually using a datatable and creating rows manually. If anyone has any idea how I could use base64 strings in either an image view I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is the code for the gridview I have created.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#FF0000" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" enabled="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Account" HeaderText="Account Number" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageURLField="ImageURL" HeaderText="Image" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is the c# code I have right now to create an entry in the gridview.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Account",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("ImageURL",typeof(string))});

        string URL = "data:image/jpg;base64,";

        string encodedString = //base64 string here


        URL += encodedString;

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "Steve", "************1111", URL);

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incredibly hacky, but it works:

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#FF0000" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    DataSource='<%# GetData() %>' runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" enabled="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Account" HeaderText="Account Number" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageURL" HeaderText="Image" HtmlEncode="false" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Account",typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("ImageURL",typeof(string))});

    string URL = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";

    string encodedString = ""; // base64-encoded image data goes here

    URL += encodedString;

    URL = $"<img src=\"{URL}\">";

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    dr["ID"] = 1;
    dr["Name"] = "Steve";
    dr["Account"] = "************1111";
    dr["ImageUrl"] = URL;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I tried to use code like this the URL = $"<img src=\"{URL}\">"; line keeps giving me an unexpected character '$', Invalid Expression term ", and ; expected errors. Not quite sure why since I have been checking and everything seems to be in order. I am also having problems with GridView1 not existing in the current context when I try to show the table somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Try this instead: `URL = "<img src=\"" + URL + "\">";`

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly and yeah it is kinda hacky but hey I've been slamming my head against a wall for a few days to figure that out.